# Help in this proof on DVRs

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand this proof:

[image]

Anyone could clarify the converse please?

I really need help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part(s) do you want clarified?

If you can fill in the details for the first sentence of the proof, then you can use the result that **a commutative ring is local if and only if the set of non-units is an ideal**  (in which case, it is the unique maximal ideal).  You can find a proof of this result [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101bS07/Math101b_notesB6.pdf).

Now for the statement about ideals.  Given a nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$, let $m = \min \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} : t^n \in I\}$.  (You should check that this set is nonempty so that it has a minimum.)  I claim that $I = (t^m)$.

First since $I \neq 0$, then there is a nonzero $x \in I$.  By assumption $x = u t^k$ for some unit $u$ and some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  Then $t^k = u^{-1} (u t^k) = u^{-1} x \in I$ since $I$ is an ideal.  Thus $\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} : t^n \in I\}$ is nonempty, hence has a minimum which we denote by $m$.  Since $t^m \in I$, then $(t^m) \subseteq I$, so it remains to show the reverse inclusion.  Given $r \in I$, then $r = u t^n$ by assumption.  Since $m$ is the minimum, then $n \geq m$, so $r = u t^n = (u t^{n - m}) t^m \in (t^m)$.  Thus $I = (t^m)$, as desired.

Comment: If you could give more details I would be very grateful, thanks

Comment: @user42912 I'm happy to give more details, but I'm not sure what you'd like me to clarify.  Is there a particular point or points you'd like me to elaborate on?

Comment: I didn't understand why the ideals in $R$ are principals. thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!! Great answer.